# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass, on user model create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do one handle facebook user that dont provide some value? I am using the koala gem and omniauth.

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

app/models/user.rb:14:in `block in from_omniauth'
app/models/user.rb:5:in `tap'
app/models/user.rb:5:in `from_omniauth'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

And I get this error because the facebook user my app is trying to autenticate dosent have some data values that my app want, like location, education history etc..

A new user process, beging in the SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
  end
end
```

Then in the user model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
  user.provider = auth["provider"]
  user.uid = auth["uid"]
  user.name = auth["info"]["name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.first_name = auth["info"]["first_name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.last_name = auth["info"]["last_name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.image = auth["info"]["image"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.email = auth["info"]["email"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.gender = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["gender"] if (!auth["extra"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"].blank?)
  user.location = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]["name"] if (!auth["extra"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"].blank?)          
  user.token = auth["credentials"]["token"] unless auth["credentials"].blank?


    # highschool data
    user.highschool_name = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][0]["school"]["name"] if (!auth["extra"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][0]["school"].blank?)
    user.highschool_year = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][0]["year"]["name"] if (!auth["extra"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][0]["year"].blank?)
    # graduate school data
    user.graduateschool_name = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][1]["school"]["name"] if (!auth["extra"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][1]["school"].blank?)
    user.graduateschool_year = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][1]["year"]["name"] if (!auth["extra"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["education"][1]["year"].blank?)

  user.add_friends
  user.save!
      user
 end 
end
end
```

Comment: note that you are missing `user = where(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is in line 14 for you User model file like for example if `auth["credentials"]` is nil `auth["credentials"]["token"]` will give the same error you got.

Put checks in line when you assigning the values, e.g., `user.token = auth["credentials"]["token"] unless auth["credentials"].blank?`

UPDATE

```
  user.first_name = auth["info"]["first_name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.last_name = auth["info"]["last_name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.image = auth["info"]["image"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.email = auth["info"]["email"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.gender = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["gender"] if (!auth["extra"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"].blank?)
  user.location = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]["name"] if (!auth["extra"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"].blank? && !auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"].blank?)
  user.token = auth["credentials"]["token"] unless auth["credentials"].blank?
```

Comment: should I put checks in every line? or just in the token field?

Comment: every field starting from user.name field as to cover all the possibilities for e.g. `auth["info"]` may be nil will make those fail

Comment: is there not a another way to handle all of them?, it feel kinda repetitiv to do .blank? in all the user.fields

Comment: sorry I am not aware of. I have updated the answer with blank? check

Comment: please check my update, is this correct? beacuse I am getting error like this: SQLite3::BusyException: cannot rollback transaction - SQL statements in progress: rollback transaction

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Object.try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method.

```
user.first_name = auth["info"].try(:[], "first_name")
```

But the best way to go should be

```
unless auth["info"].blank? 
  user.first_name = auth["info"]["first_name"]
  user.last_name = auth["info"]["last_name"]
  user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
  user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
end
```

Comment: If you do "unless auth["info"].blank?" and there are some data values empty, then it would break. so going for check for each values is more accurate.

Comment: It won't break, it will just set them to nil, which is the same as not setting them to begin with.